# wp_set_post_terms() seems very slow

Tags: performance, wp-insert-post

Is it normal for `wp_set_post_terms()` to be very slow?

When `wp_insert_post()` it takes about 1 second. Adding 4 `wp_set_post_terms()` 7 - 10 seconds to the operation.

Pseudo code example:

```
$values = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5', 'value_6'];

$post_id = '1234';
$taxonomy = 'offerings';

wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $values, $taxonomy );
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $values, $taxonomy );
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $values, $taxonomy );
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $values, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: Why would you call something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done a batch import of about 200 posts, with 5 taxonomies attached to them and each of the posts a few terms. It took about 5-10 seconds to do the whole batch.

So no, it shouldn't be this slow.

Comment: I tried to use `tax_input` as part of `wp_insert_post()` and it worked way better performance wise. Pretty much same as `wp_insert_post()` without `tax_input`.